# Picasa Login in iphone

Tags: iphone, gdata-api, picasa

Hi i'm a newbie to iphone application development..
present i'm working on ***Picasa web albums***..i integrated well in my project ,but i was stucked in a situation where passing user credentials...

i'm using **GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch** in order to validate user...
so when i use GTMOAuth i get user email only..
inorder get his info i should pass username and password..

or is there any way to get useralbums...

as of now i came to know that if we pass authentication token we can get user albums,but i was unable to get authentication token...so please help on this..

thanks in advance...

Comment: Please provide the code you already have... This will make things easier for you.

Comment: @iSee which code can i post my project contains a lot of code ...actually i need the procedure to get user albums

Comment: The piece of code relevant to the validation (not from the library itself, only code you have written). \n You could also refer to this link [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction#Example_Applications)

Comment: @iSee i've implemented according to that and i got the albums of the user who ever logged in (before implementing OAuth), since there we can directly pass user credentials ,but after implementing OAuth we should pass authentication token ....i was stuck over here getting user authentication token..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are letting the user sign in with OAuth 2, there is no need for the username and password when using the photos API.

If you are using the GData library for the Picasa Web Albums fetches, just set the service object's authorizer to the OAuth 2 auth object, like

```
[service setAuthorizer:auth];
```

as mentioned [here](http://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/wiki/Introduction#Using_the_Authentication_Tokens).